What is the theological and literary significance of the shift from the plural "those who are poor"(James 2:5) to the singular "the poor" (James 2:6)?
In the text of James 2:5-6, an interesting change in grammatical construction is observed: in verse 5, the word "poor" is in the plural ("those who are poor in the world"), while in verse 6 it appears in the singular ("the poor"). What is the theological and literary significance of this transition from the plural to the singular?
James 2:5-6 KJV

Hearken, my beloved brethren, Hath not God chosen the poor of this world rich in faith, and heirs of the kingdom which he hath promised to them that love him? But ye have despised the poor. Do not rich men oppress you, and draw you before the judgment seats?


English idiom, at least, would allow "the poor man" to stand for poor men in general.

ContrastConsider: the first word, poor, referred to all those in the world, emphasizing that they are many. Hence the plural.
The second usage must be singular, since the small congregation James is addressing could---and was---mistreating the individual poor person(s) they were individually, personally acquainted with---not the whole world of poor people.
There does not seem to be further significance in this grammatical composition. Albeit, let us not lose the importance of James admonition, by sinking into details of grammar. Surely there is a poor family in our Sunday service that we can invite to dinner this week!

This is uncomplicated.
James 2:5 - "Poor plural"
"poor" must be plural because it is the implied subject of the implied object of "heirs" which could not be singular.  That is, one cannot say:

"the poor (singular as a class) is an heir".  One must say:
"the poor (plural) are heirs

James 2:6 - "Poor singular"
By contrast, "poor" singular is simply acting as collective noun for all poor people as a class of Christians.
However, there is a simpler way to understand the singular reference in James 2:6 as referring back to the (singular) poor man in V2.  However, even this hypothetical "poor man" stands for the attitude that church members show the poor as a class.

By contrast, "poor" singular is simply acting as collective noun for all poor people as a class of Christians. Do you have any other examples in Greek for this statement?

@Betho's - this is common knowledge about simple Greek grammar.

The fact that "the poor" is singular in Jam 2:6 is also significant, I think, for the way it aligns with our treatment of Christ (cf. Mt 25:34-45).
